# Converting a sentence into Pig Latin

Tags: python, python-3.8

I'm fairly new to Python and one of the practice projects I'm trying to do is converting sentences into pig latin. The original project was just converting words into pig latin, but I want to expand this into converting sentences.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import sys
print("Pig Latin Maker")

VOWELS = 'aeiouy'

while True:
    word = input ("Write a Word: ")

    if word[0] in VOWELS:
        pig_Latin = word + 'way'
    else:
        pig_Latin = word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay'
    print ()
    print ("{}".format(pig_Latin), file=sys.stderr)

    end = input ("\n\n Press N\n")
    if end.lower() == "n":
        sys.exit()
```

The plan is to modify this so it splits all the words in the input sentence, converts each word to pig latin, and then spits it back out as one sentence but I'm not really sure how to do that.

I'm using Python 3.8. Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the words in a list, use **`listofwords = input('Write your sentence: ').split()`**.

Then, you can combine the list of pig-latin words doing **`print(' '.join(listofpiglatin))`**.

```py
import sys
print("Pig Latin Maker")
VOWELS = 'aeiouy'

while True:
    listofwords = input ("Write a Sentence: ").split()  # splits by spaces
    listofpiglatin = []
    for word in listofwords:
        if word[0] in VOWELS:
            pig_Latin = word + 'way'
        else:
            pig_Latin = word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay'
        listofpiglatin.append(pig_Latin)  # adds your new pig-latin word to our list
    print()
    print(' '.join(listofpiglatin))  # spits the words back as a sentence
    end = input ("\n\n Press n")
    if end.lower() == "n":
        sys.exit()
```

I hope that this helps you learn!

Answer (score 0):

You could split the sentence by the space character into separate strings each containing a word. You can then apply your current algorithm to every single word in that sentence. `str` has a method `split` which returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

Put your algorithm into a function:

```
def makePigLatin(word):
    <your code here>
    return latinWord
```

As other users mentioned, split the input and assign to a list:

```
words = input('blah').split()
```

Then apply your function to each word in the list:

```
translatedWords = map(makePigLatin, words)
```

Print them back out by joining them together:

```
print(' '.join(translatedWords))
```

Comment: There is quite a neat feature of `re.sub` that you can give it a function as the second argument where you would normally put a replacement pattern. Once you have a `makePigLatin` function, you modify it very slightly to make it accept a match object - essentially just extract the original word as `matchobj.group()`, then in the main code all you need to do is `re.sub("[A-Za-z]+", makePigLatin, input_string)` and it will take care of the rest, leaving any non-word character unchanged...